# CSS 3 - Scaling CSS Transitions

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to scale an image when you mouseenter, which is working. I would like the image to gradually scale up with an ease transition. I used ease-in-out, which it's not working. Any suggestions?

Also, I used addClass & removeClass twice in the jquery code. Is there a way to only use it once?

Thanks!

```
 <style>
    .image {
      opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .image.opaque {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .size{
    transform:scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.2); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.2); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -webkit-transition: scale 2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: scale 2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: scale 2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: scale 2s ease-in-out;    
    transition: scale 2s ease-in-out;
     transition: opacity 2s;
      }
  </style>



 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $(".image").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).addClass("opaque");
        $(this).addClass("size");
      });

      $(".image").mouseleave(function() {
       $(this).removeClass("opaque");
        $(this).removeClass("size");
      });

    });
 <div id="gallery">
    <h3>Gallery of images</h3>
    <img class="image" src="images/gnu.jpg" height="200px" width="250px">
    <img class="image" src="images/tiger.jpg" height="200px" width="250px">
    <img class="image" src="images/black_rhino.jpg" height="200px" width="250px">
    <img class="image" src="images/cape_buffalo.jpg" height="200px" width="250px">
  </div>
```

Comment: I used hover in a previous example that was working perfectly. However, our professor would like for us to css + jquery. I can't use hover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use jQuery instead of css :hover. Move your scale function to another class. There is also the problem with how you write transition.

```
.size{
    -webkit-transition: 2s ease-in-out; //does not accept property like scale, opacity here
    -moz-transition: 2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: 2s ease-in-out;    
    transition: 2s ease-in-out;
     transition: 2s;
      }

.scaledSize{
transform:scale(1.2);
-ms-transform:scale(1.2); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.2); /* Safari and Chrome */    
}
```

Modify your jQuery code to add and remove this class.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wpmPF/1/)

If you want to your properties animated with different timing functions and durations, you have to write separate css properties: `transition-property`, `transition-timing-function`, `transition-duration`. Like this:

```
.size{
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition-property: scale, opacity;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out, linear;
    transition-duration: 2s, 2s;
    }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wpmPF/3/)

With your code, you could try:

```
<style>
    .image {
      transition-property: scale, opacity;
      transition-timing-function: ease-in-out, linear;
      transition-duration: 2s, 2s; 
      opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .image.opaque {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .size{
    transform:scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.2); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.2); /* Safari and Chrome */
   }
  </style>

 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $(".image").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).addClass("opaque");
        $(this).addClass("size");
      });

      $(".image").mouseleave(function() {
       $(this).removeClass("opaque");
        $(this).removeClass("size");
      });

    });
 <div id="gallery">
    <h3>Gallery of images</h3>
    <img class="image" src="images/gnu.jpg" height="200px" width="250px">
    <img class="image" src="images/tiger.jpg" height="200px" width="250px">
    <img class="image" src="images/black_rhino.jpg" height="200px" width="250px">
    <img class="image" src="images/cape_buffalo.jpg" height="200px" width="250px">
  </div>
```

Comment: Yep. The last one did the trick. Thanks for clarifying that for me!